# How do I prove that $T(x,y,z)\mapsto (x,y)$ maps Lebesgue-measurable sets to Lebesgue-measurable sets?

Tags: measure-theory

Formally saying,

> Let $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $n>m$.
>
> Define $T(x)_i=x_i \forall 1≦i≦m \bigwedge x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> Then $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear transformation
>
> how do i prove that $T(E)$ is Lebesgue-measurable when $E$ is Lebesgue measurable?

I know that any Lipschitz continuous function maps measurable sets to measurable sets when $n≦m$. I want to generalize this to any $n,m$.

Please help. Thank you :)

Comment: I know the borel-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the product of the sigma algebra of $\mathbb{R}$, but i haven't prove this result for Lebesgue measurable sets. So please avoid this direction of proof.

Comment: Why use symbols like $\forall$ and $\wedge$ when there are perfectly good words like *for all* and *and*?! (and these are shorter to type than those!)

Comment: If you pick a non-lebesgue measurable set A in the plane and to each of its points add a zero coordinate at the end, you get a lebesgue measurable set B in 3-space (because it is contained in a plane, which has measure zero and we have completeness)  The image under the T in your title of B is A.

Comment: @Mariano is there any problem with using $\forall$ instead of *for all*? / So this is false, right? Thank you!